# Regex - optional character at the end of a string

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern almost working but I can't seem to get it just right. I'm trying to capture the part of string after the first hyphen but that part can be inside of square brackets so I marked them as optional and it works for the opening bracket but the closing bracket matches if it's present. So my question is, are optional characters at the end of a string matching differently than elsewhere? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the pattern I have now:

```
^start of string \- \[?(.*)\]?$
```

The example strings:

```
start of string - match - this part
start of string - [match - this part]
```

The results I'm getting:

```
match - this part
match - this part]
```

And the wanted result in both cases:

```
match - this part
```

Comment: The dot should be non greedy `^start of string \- \[?(.*?)\]?$`

Comment: Thank you, this is a very elegant solution and I wasn't even aware of the concept of characters being greedy in regex, I learned something important so thank you for that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the closing bracket denying it in your group capture

```
^start of string \\- \\[?(.*[^\\]])\\]?$
```